# Action on drop down option select

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, html-select

I am developing an Ruby on Rails application and currently I need to make specific action depending on selection of drop down item.

I have the following code:

```
<%= collection_select(:cat, :cat_id, @cats, :id, :full_name) %>
```

How can I trigger a specific action when user chooses one option? How to access that ID of that option and do the specific action?

Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we have model like this:

```
create_table "doctors", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
end

class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :appointments
    has_many :users, :through => :appointments

    def full_name
    "#{name} #{last_name}"
  end
end
```

`Home` controller:

```
class StaticController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @doctors = Doctor.all
  end
end
```

We can generate drop down menu like this inside `Home` View:

```
<div>
    <p>Pick a doctor</p>
    <%= collection_select(:doctor, :id, @doctors, :id, :full_name) %>
</div>
```

And after user chooses another value from drop down menu, some action is triggered:

```
$("#doctor_id").change(function() {
    var selectedVal = $(this).val();

    // Do something depending on selected value
});
```

That's it :)

Answer (score 0):

Rails creates ids with the singular form of the resource name followed by the name of the attribute. E.g. `Post.title => "post_title"`.

Following your example code it would result in something like

```
<select id="post_cat_id"></select>
```

see: [dom_id](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/RecordIdentifier.html#method-i-dom_id)